# without reload page load all data in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**how can I do without reloading page load all data in react js?**
I am creating treeview and in this node selected node value display in right-side view but refreshing page after showing the results.

Comment: you can do ajax call using fetch or axios it does not need to reload the page

Comment: please give me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

For this i would be the best practice to user Redux in combination with SocketIO.
For a good example read this: [Using socket.io in React-Redux app to handle real-time data.](https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/using-socket-io-in-react-redux-app-to-handle-real-time-data-c0e734297795)